# A variant of two-counter machine

Tags: computability

I would like to show that the halting problem for some variant of two counter machine (Minsky machine) is undecidable:

instead of "if c=0 goto i else goto j", there are "if c>d goto i else goto j" commands (where c,d are the two counters). The inc\dec\goto\halt commands remain the same.

It is not hard to show that this problem is undecidable with 3 counters (for example, given an instance of the original problem, adding a third counter e that always equals 0, and we have that c!=0 iff c>e, d!=0 iff d>e).
My question is - is this variant known to be undecidable, with only two counters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not universal, because it could be simulated by a 1-counter machine (with the jump-if-zero instruction) that stores the difference of the two counters  and an additional state (or program section)  that keeps track if the difference is positive or negative. But a 1-counter machine is not universal.

Comment: How do you simulate the dec instruction (which is really “if $a>0$ then $a:=a-1$” as the counter cannot become negative)? If you only keep track of the difference, you cannot tell when one of the simulated counters becomes $0$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: good point. I'll check if other decidability resuts about counter machine variants can be used.